# Reduce console output for Flutter in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

In most of the tutorials on YouTube, the output shown in console is mostly the output made by user itself (by that I mean output created by calling 
`print()` - my console is a mess though)

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the output only to things I call `print()` on in Android studio?

Comment: change `finest` to something else - i mean top-left spinner in the `console` tab

Comment: tryied all of them - nothing changes - besides three last ones (warning, severe , shout) thoese clean console totally and there is no output at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now, there is no way of showing logs which are only from `print()` statement. However there is a workaround.

Whenever you write something in `print` statement, you can add some prefix to it like instead of writing it as

```
print('This is my log message');  // earlier way
```

You can write it as

```
print('myTag: This is my log message');  // newer way
```

After that all you need to do is use the search box functionality

[image]

---

**Note**: You can also create live template for `print` so that `myTag` is automatically added to it.

Comment: ok, ty for information cops! will award U "50" points in next 24 h

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dart Dev tools and set up a filter to get only the print statements
Next to the hot restart, you can find the button get Dart Dev tools
In Dart dev tools go to the logging tab and create a filter k:stdout